# Phonegap:Is it possible to play multiple videos simultaneously on same page using html5 video tag?

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, video

I am using HTML5 video tag to play video in phonegap app.In my app I have one listing page with multiple videos. I want to play them simultaneously.

**PROBLEM
-------**
To play video in phonegap android i used

```
$("#id").get(0).play();
$("#id1").get(0).play();
$("#id2").get(0).play();
```

With this only last one video plays and if click on other video it starts but pauses other videos.
I have no idea about problem.

### **HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
        <video class='androidVid' id='video1' style='width:100%;height:240px' muted>
            <source type='application/x-mpegURL' src='http://xx.xx.xx.xx/HLS/clawview.m3u8?t=Math.random()'>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <video class='androidVid' id='video2' style='width:100%;height:240px' muted>
            <source type='application/x-mpegURL' src='http://xx.xx.xx.xx/HLS/clawview.m3u8?t=Math.random()'>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $("#video1").get(0).play();
    $("#video2").get(0).play();
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

thanks

Comment: u have used different id for each video??

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML or create a jsfiddle

Comment: @devgon  added html .Please check it . thanks

Comment: Hi @varunnayyar did you find solution to your problem? I'm stuck in the same situation.